# Como fazer para definir um array de pages em uma função e retornar para uma variável, NAVCTRL IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em que o `app component` possui um side menu que usa um let para buscar o array de páginas, entretanto não consigo acessá-las a partir do meu provider, não conseguindo o retorno.

//quero separar a manipulacao do app em dois, então estou verificando se o usuario é admin ou comum

```
definePage() {

if(this.getBoolPages() === true) {

  this.pages = [
    { title: 'Menu', component: MenuPage },
    { title: 'menu', component: MenuPage }
  ];

} else {

  this.pages = [
    { title: 'Xisde', component: MenuPage }
  ];

}

return (this.pages);

}

  getBoolPages() {

return this.pagAcessoSup;

}
```

No `app.component.ts` estou tentando receber assim:

```
pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

constructor(
public platform: Platform, 
public statusBar: StatusBar,
private authProvider:AuthProvider, 
public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

this.pages = authProvider.definePage();

this.initializeApp();

}
```

Entretanto, quando é mais de um item, este simplesmente não recebe nada.

Como resolver isso?